# How to change python-path of supervisor?

Tags: python, ubuntu-16.04, gunicorn, supervisord

I'm working in a flask REST API using python3, supervisor and gunicorn. I have installed all the pip modules. when i run the supervisor's config file it shows following error. Any help would be appreciated. 
[image: Error message]

[image: supervisor's config file]

[image: log file of supervisor]

Answer (score 0):

Using virtual environment and install python 3.x to it. After that it works fine.